# How to define a constant value in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I need to run some scripts for MySQL databases. And I need to adjust the value in queries each time I run them. However, I need to specify the same value in two different places. I don't want to accidentally leave one value unchanged. Is there a way to specify the value as a constant in the script? I only have read privilege in the databases. I couldn't find the information through searching. Thanks.

Comment: You could define a session variable at the start of your script.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do what you want with MySQL @variables, or via a simple select statement as your first table and join with no ON clause (thus a cross-join), but a Cartesian result with only 1 record will never create duplicates.  Then you can use that column consistently throughout.  For example...

```
select
   from
      ( select @someNumber := 123,
               @someDate := '2017-07-23' ) sqlVars,
      OtherTable OT
   where
          OT.SomeNumberField = @someNumber
      OR  OT.OtherDateField = @someDate
```

but you can probably do similar as just a column such as

```
select
   from
      ( select 123 as someNumber,
               '2017-07-23' as someDate ) sqlVars,
      OtherTable OT
   where
          OT.SomeNumberField = sqlVars.someNumber
      OR  OT.OtherDateField = sqlVars.someDate
```

Of course, standard join, left-join, etc to multiple tables should be able to see the columns either way with the table as the first in the list so it is visible all down-stream.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a variable at the beginning of your query, you can use that throughout.